# How to use ::before in css to hide existing elements and append new one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make some modifications in UI based on some conditions. I am assuming that CSS will be the best option. This is what I want to achieve

This code

```
<td role="gridcell" class="k-edit-cell k-dirty-cell" data-role="editable">
::before
<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg field-validation-error"
 style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="MinAcceptableText" 
 data-val-msg-for="MinAcceptableText" 
 id="MinAcceptableText_validationMessage" 
 role="alert">
 <span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span>
 MinAcceptableText is not valid<div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
 </div>
 <input type="number"
 step="0.01" name="MinAcceptableText" id="MinAcceptableFloatId" 
 data-bind="value: 
 MinAcceptableValue" class="k-number k-invalid" 
 style="width:70% ; outline:none;" 
 aria-invalid="true"></td>
```

I need to convert to this using css classes

```
<td role="gridcell" class="k-dirty-cell" data-role="editable">
::before
<span class="k-dirty"></span>
0.09 
</td>
```

I can create  and append to container but I am not sure how to use styles. This is how I am doing CSS

```
$('<style>').text(".k-widget.k-tooltip-validation {display: none!important;} ").appendTo(document.head);
```

How can I fix my issue ?

This is one of grid I am doing inline editing. Usually when I click outside automatically values will be saved and UI will updated as I am asking above. This is one of exceptional case where UI is not getting updated (changes not saving automatically) so I need to do it manually.